# How do I make a div in which I can scroll through md-cards?

Tags: html

I have a simple webpage, that shows several cards in its main section. There are so many cards that you can only see a few in the view. My aim is a design, in which I can scroll through these cards. Therefore I added `overflow: scroll` to the div with the id 'XXX'.

However, this does not work as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

So what do I need to change in my code below, in order to make the list of cards scrollable?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.13/angular-material.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.13/docs.css'>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    .example-card {
        max-width: 400px;
        }
    </style>

    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp" id="ggg3g54g5g35">
        <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; top:0;   height:100%; background-color:lightblue;">
            <div id="XXX" style="position:fixed;width:80%;top:32%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);overflow: scroll">
                <md-card><md-card-content>A is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>B is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>C is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>D is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>E is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>F is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>G is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>H is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>I is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>J is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>K is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>L is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>M is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>N is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>O is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>P is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>Q is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>R is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>S is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>T is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>U is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>V is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>W is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>X is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>Y is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content>Z is a letter in the alphabet.</md-card-content></md-card>
                <md-card><md-card-content><p id="someID">What else can I say?</p></md-card-content></md-card>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#eeeeee; position:fixed; bottom:0; width:100%" ng-cloak="" layout="column" layout-align="bottom bottom" layout-padding="">
            <p>I wonder: How can I scroll through the cards above?</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <!--
    Copyright 2018 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved. 
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be found
    in the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
    -->
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.13/angular-material.js'></script>      
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set a height of 100% for the div tag with id="XXX" and also use overflow-x:none to hide the horizontal scroll bar

```
<div id="XXX" style="position:fixed;width:80%;top:32%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);overflow: scroll;overflow-x:hidden; height:100%;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a height to your inner div to make it scrollable.
Change your div id="XXX" to this:

```
<div id="XXX" style="height:50%;position:fixed;width:80%;top:32%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);overflow: scroll">
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing here has nothing to do with Angular-Material, but rather just plain HTML. You are required to understand how overflow works in order to add scroll bars to your elements. Scroll bars are there to solve overflow "problems", not much more.

The way this works is that whenever a child element is bigger in size than its parent, an overflow will happen. When this happens, you could apply a CSS rule to do whatever you would like to happen to solve regarding problem (e.g. `overflow-y: scroll;`). You desire to solve overflow by using a scroll bar. The following example shows you how this exactly works:

```css
#parent {
  /*Height must be smaller than its child to make an overflow happen*/
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  /*The following allows for a solution to deal with the overflow, which in this case would be the desired scrollbar.*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#child {
  /*Height must be bigger than its parent to make an overflow happen*/
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

#parent, #child {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have any more questions regarding overflow, please let me know.